# How to use ODataQueryOpions with lower Camel case?

Tags: c#, odata, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using the latest Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData (7.0.0-beta2).
I am trying to use ODataQueryOptions<> to get OData parameters from the OData query with **Camel case** properties names.

I have used `builder.EnableLowerCamelCase();`
Everything is working fine when calling my controller endpoints with Pascal case properties names. For example:

URL: `/myentities?$orderby=**Id**`
Controller action: `public async Task<IEnumerable<MyEntity>> Get(ODataQueryOptions<MyEntity> options)`

But as soon as I use camel case names (`/myentities?$orderby=**id**`), the OData throw a validation exception:

> ODataException: Could not find a property named 'id' on type
>   'MyNamespace.MyEntity'.
>   Microsoft.OData.UriParser.EndPathBinder.GeneratePropertyAccessQueryForOpenType(EndPathToken
>   endPathToken, SingleValueNode parentNode)
>   Microsoft.OData.UriParser.EndPathBinder.BindEndPath(EndPathToken
>   endPathToken) Microsoft.OData.UriParser.MetadataBinder.Bind(QueryToken
>   token)
>   Microsoft.OData.UriParser.OrderByBinder.ProcessSingleOrderBy(BindingState
>   state, OrderByClause thenBy, OrderByToken orderByToken)
>   Microsoft.OData.UriParser.OrderByBinder.BindOrderBy(BindingState
>   state, IEnumerable orderByTokens)
>   Microsoft.OData.UriParser.ODataQueryOptionParser.ParseOrderByImplementation(string
>   orderBy, ODataUriParserConfiguration configuration, ODataPathInfo
>   odataPathInfo)
>   Microsoft.OData.UriParser.ODataQueryOptionParser.ParseOrderBy()
>   Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Query.OrderByQueryOption.get_OrderByClause()
>   Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Query.OrderByQueryOption.get_OrderByNodes()
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.PropertyHelper.CallNullSafePropertyGetter(Func getter, object target)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.DefaultComplexObjectValidationStrategy+Enumerator.GetModel(object
>   container, ModelMetadata property)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.DefaultComplexObjectValidationStrategy+Enumerator+<>c__DisplayClass10_0.b__1()
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation.ValidationEntry.get_Model()
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation.ValidationVisitor.VisitChildren(IValidationStrategy
>   strategy)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation.ValidationVisitor.VisitComplexType(IValidationStrategy
>   defaultStrategy)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation.ValidationVisitor.Visit(ModelMetadata
>   metadata, string key, object model)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation.ValidationVisitor.VisitChildren(IValidationStrategy
>   strategy)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation.ValidationVisitor.VisitComplexType(IValidationStrategy
>   defaultStrategy)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation.ValidationVisitor.Visit(ModelMetadata
>   metadata, string key, object model)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation.ValidationVisitor.Validate(ModelMetadata
>   metadata, string key, object model)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.DefaultObjectValidator.Validate(ActionContext
>   actionContext, ValidationStateDictionary validationState, string
>   prefix, object model)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ParameterBinder+d__6.MoveNext()

I understand that `builder.EnableLowerCamelCase();` is just about using Camel case when serializing OData entities "responses" but how to properly create an OData API with asp.net core using Camel case names and ODataQueryOptions<> ?
Do I have to implement a custom binder or is there a native way to do it ?

I found an issue that may be related to my problem here: https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/889

Has anyone managed to implement this without any hack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is working fine with latest OData packages (7 beta4 or final) and without any additional setting.
I think I should have had an old OData package or a wrong setting on my EDM OData model when I posted this question...